# Trouble with regular expression catching strings that begins and ends with alpha character and contains dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches strings such as:

**N1-112S**

So far I have succeeded with the following (although I'm not really sure why it works):

```
item.match(/^\D.-/)
```

I'd like to further bolster the results by ensuring that the last character is A-Z as well.

I'd appreciate some help on a good regular expression for matching this pattern. Thanks!

Comment: So far nothing is clear wit this `N1-112S` excerpt last A-Z. is any part constant. you accept answer base on sombudy reading mind. yuo never get what yuo want that way, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to match a string that starts with an uppercase ASCII letter, then has a digit, then a hyphen, then 1 or more digits and then an ASCII letter at the end of the string use

```
/^[A-Z]\d-\d+[A-Z]$/.test(item)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOwtxt/1). Also, to test if a regex matches some string or not, I'd recommend `RegExp#test`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\d` - an ASCII digit
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d+`  - 1+ digits
- `[A-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `$` - end of string.

**Variations**

To match any alphanumeric chars after hyphen till the end of string, you need to change the above pattern a bit:

```
/^[A-Z]\d-[\dA-Z]*[A-Z]$/
```

The second `\d+` is changed to `[\dA-Z]*`, any 0 or more ASCII digits or letters.

If there can be any chars after `-`, use `.*` or `[^]` instead of a `\d+`:

```
/^[A-Z]\d-.*[A-Z]$/
```

Comment: It works great I already tested. And thanks for posting the walk-through of the assertions and the link. I need to get better with regexes and the extra info is very helpful.